# Why sometimes the option Archive disappears from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Ssometimes I'm using Visual Studio, go to Compilation > Recompile solution and then the option Archive is there, other times I recompile the solution and suddenly the option Archive is not there anymore forcing me to restart visual studio. After the restart Archive is there. Is this a normal thing? I'm Using VS Community 2017.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/250524/after-latest-visual-studio-update-the-archive-butt.html

Comment: If that doesn't help then use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to file your own bug report.  Reporting the VS2017 version is absolutely crucial, use Help > About to see it.

Comment: @HansPassant hey, I readed it but in my case it's not permanently disabled, it really disappers from the menu and after restarting it's there again.